# get last day of last year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

Can anyone help me to get last day of last year i have 3 case :
if `startdate = 04-12-2015` and day of this date is between 1 ->10 
   get `startdate =01-01-2015` and `endDate = 30-11-2015`

if `startdate = 12-12-2015` and day of this date isn't between 1 ->10 
   get `startdate =01-01-2015` and `endDate = 12-12-2015`

if `startdate = 04-01-2016` and day of this date is between 1 ->10 
   get `startdate =01-01-2015` and `endDate = 31-12-2015`

Update : there 's new case :
if `startdate = 12-12-2016` and day of this date isn't between 1 ->10 
   get `startdate =01-01-2015` and `endDate = 12-12-2015`  so i need help in this case

```
 DECLARE        @endDate      Date 
DECLARE     @startDate    Date   
SET         @startDate = '2016/12/12'   --'2016/01/04' GETDATE() '2015/12/12'
--Check if startDate are between January and October
    IF (FORMAT(@startDate,'dd') between 01 AND 10 )  AND ( YEAR(@startDate) <> YEAR(GETDATE()) )
       BEGIN
            PRINT 'IF loop <> year'
            SET   @endDate   = CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(ms,-2,dateadd(year,0,dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,@startDate),0))),106) 
            SET   @startDate = CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,@endDate),0),106)
            PRINT @endDate 
            PRINT @startDate
       END

    ELSE IF FORMAT(@startDate,'dd') between 01 AND 10 
       BEGIN
            PRINT 'IF loop current year'
            SET   @endDate   = CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(d,-(day(getdate())),getdate()),106) 
            SET   @startDate = CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,@endDate),0),106)
            PRINT @endDate 
            PRINT @startDate
       END
    ELSE IF ( FORMAT(@startDate,'dd') not between 01 AND 10 ) AND ( YEAR(@startDate) <> YEAR(GETDATE()) )
       BEGIN
            PRINT 'ILSE loop not current year'
            SET   @endDate   = @startDate 
            SET   @startDate = CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,@endDate),0),106)
            PRINT @endDate 
            PRINT @startDate
       END
    ELSE 
       BEGIN
            PRINT 'ILSE loop  current year'
            SET   @endDate   = @startDate 
            SET   @startDate = CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,@endDate),0),106)
            PRINT @endDate 
            PRINT @startDate
       END
```

Comment: It's ok  , i fixed it by adding this : `SET   @endDate   = DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yyyy, @startDate, GETDATE()), @startDate)`

Comment: Please add your solution as an Answer rather than a comment.